# How can I disable web links in Intellij Idea run output?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I just a Java application in the IDE, it displays the output in the 'run' panel. However, it makes all the http:// links into clickable items, and this is causing problems (slow scrolling of output, mouse goes flickery on mouse over).

It's just plain wasteful, so I'd like to make it into pure plain text. I couldn't find any options, is this even possible (aside from mangling the output - my last resort)?

Comment: Not possible. Unless you make a plugin.

Comment: You could also create an issue at JetBrains' tracker and complain about the problems - preferably with some hard facts, measurements, screenshots, or even an example app. They are usually very responsive: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: Thanks. I feared this was the case, but it seemed to be a good question to ask here. Having raw, unadorned output would be a good option, so I'll create a feature request. It does make me wonder though... what other outputs get transformed, and how can I abuse this... ;-)

Comment: Take a look at https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console

Comment: Grep Console looks mighty useful, even if it doesn't solve this it could be a valuable addition, thanks for the recommendation!